# how to have tilda and vector above a symbol

Tags: math-mode, arrows, tilde

Is there a way to have symbol with a `tilde` and `arrow` stacked on top of each other? I tried `$\vec \tilde{p}$` but it doesn't look good.

Comment: Try   $\vec{\tilde{p}}$

Comment: another way using `mathtools`-package: `$\overset{\tilde{\rightarrow}}{p}$`

Comment: You should load the `amsmath` package and write `$\vec{\tilde{p}}$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nicest, in my opinion, is obtained with a `\widetilde` and the `esvect` package. In most cases, we need to add some kerning:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}

 \begin{document}

\[ \vv{\!\widetilde p}\qquad\vec{\tilde p}\qquad \overset{\rightarrow}{\!\widetilde p}\qquad \overrightarrow{\!\widetilde p} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]